# Is there any solution to improve the performance and scalability of a web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture, refactoring, microservices

I have couple of questins, if someone could explain me the following scenario.

When we started out building our product, we were a very small team, and we needed to prove value quickly. Therefore it made a lot of sense to build the whole product into a single web application, as that made it very easy to manage. However, as the company and product grew over the years, we started to face some problems with this architecture:

- Some actions on the site are computationally very heavy, so they take a long time to complete (it becomes a larger and larger problem because of an increase in the amount of data that needs to be processed)
- We have introduced more and more concepts into the application, like Invoices, Debtors, Creditors, Payments, Bills, Receipts, etc
- The team has grown, so there is a higher chance that we will "step on each others toes"

To be completely honest, we have solved or are solving these pains already, but they still set the scene for some interesting questions:

**- Which actions would you take to improve the performance and scalability of a web app like that?**

Comment: First, pleae read the speed rant: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ to verify there is a problem that needs solving. And make sure you clearly defined the problem.

Comment: Unfortunatley your question is orders of magnitude to wide and ambigious to help you. The question is likely to be closed in short order as it is not salvageable. If you got a _specific_ problem, we might be able to help you.

Comment: @Cristopher I know that some of this question may repeted here or maybe answer here but I could not find anything about the problem. I have no idea how to specify and clearly descripe the problem. Only thinks which I can meansion is this couple of question.

Comment: You do not have **a** problem. You got a whole list of possible problems and want solutions for all of them. Questions should be about one specific problem, having one (mostly) unambigious answer. This boils down to "help me design our software makign process". Leagues to wide. | A specific problem would be "Some actions on the site are computationally very heavy, so they take a long time to complete (it becomes a larger and larger problem because of an increase in the amount of data that needs to be processed)", with concrete data and questions how to improove it.

Comment: Could I please re-design my question and ask specific one ?

Comment: You have lots of questions that you need to ask separately, and not all are suitable for Stackoverflow. I suggest you look for other forums in addition to SO, such as the msdev.chat Slack channel, or the F# Slack if F# can be of interest.

Comment: And don't forget to search for answers before asking. There are plenty of answers already that can help you and your team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems you are describing are precisely the ones that a microservices architecture tries to solve.

First of all, you should start to identify which parts of your application are independent of others (for example the billing probably is independent of the rest) so you identify the different "bounded contexts" or different business domains.

Then you need to know how is the communication flow between the different parts of your application and define the best strategy to keep this communication as little as possible and how to do that between different services.

Then when you have the design on how to split the application, communication, data model etc, you should start to create one by one smaller services with this chunks of functionality from your original one and continue to do this one by one until you have the different domains decoupled in different services.

There is a lot of documentation on the internet on how to split a monolith into microservices.

When you achieve that you will have solved the scalability, the speed of delivering, and the multiple developers working in parallel problems

Answer (score 1):

May be you already did, but first step is to

```
1. run your web app through performance tab in Chrome Developer tools. This will give you complete suggestions report on improving
the performance.
2.Go to Memory tab in Chrome Developer tools and profile heap snapshot to see memory distribution.
3.In Network tab see for every navigation how many network calls you are making and how much data is getting downloaded.
4.Encode and download common images at once.
5.Remove unused assets, font families, unused and older version of libraries.
6.Minify all your js scripts
7.Check what is making your Content visualization speed lag
```